Capacitors with same capacitance but different voltage ratings
Suppose we have two capacitors that have same capacitance (same dielectric material) but different voltage ratings. Let both capacitors each be fully charged to their maximum voltages. From formula $Q=CV$ (fixing $C$ as constant), capacitor 1 has charge $Q_1$ and voltage $V_1$; capacitor 2 has charge $Q_2$ and voltage $V_2$. What makes this change in voltage without change in capacitance value? Since from $V= E d$, if we say electric field $E$ or separation between plates $d$ as the reason for the voltage variation, then it means that $C$ also changes, because of the relationship $C= \varepsilon A/d$, i.e. $E$ depends on $\varepsilon$, the dielectric constant.
For the same dielectric material, is it possible to have same capacitance and different voltage rating?

"What makes this change in voltage without change in capacitance ?" You connect the capacitor to a power supply set to give a higher voltage between its terminals?

(a) "Yes, after charging the two capacitor[s]" But you do the charging by connecting the capacitors across power supplies! (b) "Two cap. has two different voltages across it according to its rating" Your grammar is confused: are you talking about two capacitors or one capacitor? A capacitor's rating is the maximum voltage that you may safely apply to it. (c) I'm afraid that I don't understand what your difficulty is.

"What makes this change in voltage without change in capacitance?" If the capacitance is the same, then it's different charge. Not sure what you're asking here.

You've charged the capacitors to different voltages: call them $V_A$ and $V_B$. Therefore the electric fields strengths have magnitudes $E_A=\tfrac {V_A}d$ and $E_B=\tfrac {V_B}d$ and the charges are $Q_A=CV_A$ and $Q_B=CV_B$. The capacitors are identical, so $C$ is the same for each. $C$ is unaffected by $E$, because for a typical dielectric, $\epsilon$ is unaffected by $E$.

"For the same dielectric material, is it possible to have same capacitance and different voltage rating?". Yes ; making $d$ larger will enable the capacitor to stand a larger voltage without the dielectric 'breaking down' (conducting when it should be insulating). But to keep the capacitance the same we'd have to make $A$ larger (e.g. if we doubled $d$ we'd have to double $A$).

Well thanks.. making the d value large, contribute to V rating increase. But maintaining the A/d ratio same, maintains a constant C value, right?

Right ! But I'm concerned that you seem to think that the voltage rating has more significance than just a safety limit on voltage you can apply.

Yes, I think so. thanks@PhilipWood

The voltage rating means that if the capacitor has more than that much voltage, the dielectric will break down and current will flow from one plate to the other. This means the capacitor isn't acting as a capacitor any more, and in fact it might be destroyed by the breakdown process. The voltage rating is not saying that any particular voltage is always on the capacitor. The relationship $C = Q / V$ is always obeyed until $V$ goes above the voltage rating limit.

The voltage rating of a capacitor gives you the safe maximum voltage for operation given by the manufacturer. This has nothing to do with the basic physics of the capacitors, only with their failure safety.

If you connect the two capacitors in parallel then they have the same voltage across them but they carry different charges - the charge on each capacitor is in proportion to its capacitance, so that $\frac {Q_1}{C_1} = \frac {Q_2}{C_2}$.
If you connect the two capacitors in series then they carry the same charge but they have different voltages - the voltage across each capacitor is in inverse proportion to its capacitance, so that $V_1 C_1 = V_2 C_2$.
